# spfx - onpropertychange event

Tags: spfx

I have created cascading dropdown.  I need to load dropdown based on parent dropdown selection. I am trying to use onpropertychange event. but I am getting error on super.onpropertychange saying {Property 'onPropertyChange' does not exist on type 'BaseClientSideWebPart'.}

please let us know what I havve missed.

```js
 protected onPropertyChange(propertyPath: string, newValue: any):void{  
    if(propertyPath === "listDropDown"){  
      // Change only when drop down changes  
      super.onPropertyChange(propertyPath,newValue);  
      // Clears the existing data  
      this.properties.ItemsDropDown = undefined;  
      this.onPropertyChange('ItemsDropDown', this.properties.ItemsDropDown);  
      // Get/Load new items data  
      this.GetItems();  
    }  
    else {  
      // Render the property field  
      super.onPropertyChange(propertyPath, newValue);  
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `onPropertyChange`, perhaps you mean [onPropertyFieldChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/basewebpart?view=sp-typescript-latest#onpropertypanefieldchanged-propertypath--oldvalue--newvalue-) from the BaseWebPart class?

The error message is accurate - web parts don't have a method called `onPropertyChange`. The above sounds like the closest match for what you are trying to do. Note that it takes not two arguments, but three: `propertyPath`, `oldValue`, and `newValue`.